# Is there a glossary tool that can store and lookup words quickly?

Tags: information-management

My goal is to keep a personal glossary of terms for quick reference. Is there a lightweight tool that allows me to create, alphabetically sort and lookup words? For example I want to store some words:

> - AAPL : aka Apple. A big company with more money than the government has debt.
> - COMP : aka computer. A piece of technology with a keyboard.
> - Apple Pie : A good pie you can eat. Popular in Texas.

Now if I type "AAPL" it brings me to the first line:

> AAPL : aka Apple.  A big company with more money than the government has debt.

I imagine I could write these out in a text file with some kind of delimiter to seperate lines (some definitions could span a couple lines or so) and use grep. This means I would have to sort the words alphabetically myself. And I'm not always on a Unix-based machine.

I want to be able to use this tool to create my glossary of terms and also be able to copy and paste the content into a corporate website as needed.

Is there a lightweight tool that can do this quickly?

OS: Windows or OS X (support for both preferred).

Comment: Does the tool have to run on Windows *and* Mac OS X?

Comment: I use both OS's so I *prefer* OS agnostic.  However, I can function with 1 OS and I have both available to me in the office if the tool can get the job done well.

Comment: Or would you access a web-based solution, making it o/s agnostic? Or, even, if you can't find what you want for desktop, a smart-phone solution?

Comment: @Mawg Web will work.  Phones are somewhat useful, but I need to copy into the corporate website so its a maybe with VPN or sending via email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3).  I can highlight all words and hit F9 to sort lines alphabetically.  It will word wrap which allows me to view all content without creating new lines.  CTRL + F will do a find.  I can copy into a web browser easily as well.  Sublime runs on windows and mac.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's Widows only (*), alas, but it should run under Wine - I regularly use [LingoPad](http://www.ego4u.com/en/lingopad) for translating European languages.

> You can also import your own wordlists and use them parallel to the
>   existing dictionaries

Although, I would recommend contacting them and asking how to create your own dictionary, rather than adding a wordlist to an existing dictionary.

Failing that, ask them for an empty dictionary and add your worlist, or add your wordlist to a Japanese or Arabic dictionary, where there can be no clash and you will always find your own term.

> (*) There will be no further development of LingoPad under Windows in
>   the near future. However, we are planning to develop cross-platform
>   LingoPad for Mac OS X, Linux and Windows
>   So, maybe use Wine as a stop-gap?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't let me add words or copy bulk content.  I don't think it will work.

Comment: ??? I thought that you could add your own wordlists (maybe not in bulk). Anyway, nvm, glad to see that you found a solution (don't forget to accept your own answer after 2 days, for the benefit of future searchers).